# Draw portion of image on Canvas

Tags: android, image, android-canvas

I have an image of size 265x256 and I want to draw the top-left and right-bottom portion of size 16x16 at random location on Canvas
Can someone please share the concept or code to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [Canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20android.graphics.Rect,%20android.graphics.Rect,%20android.graphics.Paint%29) method

```
public void drawBitmap (Bitmap bitmap, Rect src, RectF dst, Paint paint)
```

where documentation states second argument src as

> If the source rectangle is not null, it specifies the subset of the
>   bitmap to draw.

So you can pass the rectangle of the source bitmap that you want to draw in the second argument.

Comment: between drawBitmap and createBitmap which will be more expensive?

Comment: You wanted to draw in the canvas right? Atleast that is what I understood from the questions. If you want to create bitmap from the canvas, then this answer doesn't suit you..

Comment: Regarding which one is expensive, I can't say for sure, but I think there is not much difference in performance in both case. Since in both cases, os has to iterate through each pixel, there RGB(A) values.