# programmatically edit images for puzzle usage

Tags: java, android

I'm making a sliding puzzle ( 3x3/4x4/5x5 with the lower-right corner cut out ). However I can't figure out where to start with programmatically cutting images ( which will be loaded from own gallery in sdcard or database from app ) in the puzzle pieces.
I've been looking over the internet and nothing really helped me.

What is the best way to cut up this image and store it in a new database (and still will be able to slide them)? Just a push in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: you don't have to cut it up, just draw portions of the image: [Draw portion of image on Canvas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12946609/draw-portion-of-image-on-canvas)

Comment: Heh. This sounds like the "Facebook" recruiting challenge...

Comment: I know nothing about facebook, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the PhotoGaffe app..
Its available on Google code [here](http://code.google.com/p/photogaffe/).
It allows user to choose between 3x3, 4x4, 5x5, and 6x6 puzzles.

This may help you in doing your task.

Answer (score 0):

Straight from something I'm working on at the moment!

```
    Bitmap main = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.puzzle);

    if( main.getHeight() > main.getWidth() ){
        rescalefactor =((float)screenHeight)/main.getHeight();}
    else {
        rescalefactor = ( (float)screenWidth)/main.getWidth();
    }

    main = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(main,(int)(main.getWidth()*rescalefactor),(int)(main.getHeight()*rescalefactor), false);

    Bitmap cropped;

    LinearLayout layout[] = new LinearLayout[rows];

    int x=0,y=0,i=0,j=0,width=main.getWidth()/column,height=main.getHeight()/rows;

    int count = 1;

    for(i=0;i<rows;++i)
    {
        layout[i] = new LinearLayout(this);

        for(j=0;j<column;++j)
        {
            cropped = Bitmap.createBitmap(main,x,y,width,height);
            image[i][j] = new Tile(this);
            image[i][j].setImageBitmap(cropped);
            image[i][j].row =i;image[i][j].column =j;
            image[i][j].setPadding(1, 1, 1, 1);
            image[i][j].setOnClickListener(this);
            image[i][j].setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            image[i][j].setId(count); count++;
            layout[i].addView(image[i][j]);
            x += width;
        }

        x = 0; y += height;
        root.addView(layout[i]);
    }
```

This is the line where the work is really done:

```
cropped = Bitmap.createBitmap(main,x,y,width,height);
```

The Tile class is super simple.  Just an extended ImageView with row and column fields:

```
public class Tile extends ImageView {

    public int row, column;
    public Tile(Context context)
    {  super(context);}
}
```

Comment: Will this cut my selected ages in for example 3x3=9 equal pieces and remove the 9th image in the down right corner, so the pieces will be able to slide?

Comment: Well, your question was how to chop up the bitmap, which I've answered.  Please accept my answer.  To make a blank tile, I simply make if fully transparent.  image[i-1][j-1].setAlpha(0x00);
        emptyTile = image[i-1][j-1];

        shuffleTiles();